# Get derivative of Cost function with a simple constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to intuitively understand derivating the cost function in Gradient descent, but I think there are some key points I am missing.

The algorithm tries to find the best parameter to minimze the cost function of

$ C_0 = \sum_{p=1}^{n}1/n * (y_p - C)^2 $

to a randomly generated set of datapoints, where C is the value to be minimized.

[image: Screenshot of Program]

I can actually plot the error function, but I don't understand how can I calculate the derivative of it.

The derived formula looks like this(Thanks to corrections from @Nicky Levering) : 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial C}C_0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial C} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n 
(y_p - C)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n 
\frac{\partial}{\partial C}  (y_p - C)^2 = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n (y_p - C)
= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n y_p - 2C,
\end{align*}

In which the variable $y_p$ remains, which I do not know how to differentiate, as it is a set of randomly generated numbers.

How can $C_0$ be differentiated?

---

**Update:**

After my calculations were corrected, it all clicked:

there is no way to differentiate $y_p$, as it is (in this example) a generated data set. The formula however is given for the derivative, so in order to calculate the gradient for a given C, one must go through all of the points in $y_p$ and calculate the summation manually.

Comment: Hi David! I don't get why my answer does not answer your question, since $y_p$ is independent of $C$ so the derivative I gave you is the derivative of $C_0$. Is there something else you don't understand?

Comment: Mainly about the implementation of the minimization function, but if I understand correctly $y_p$ has to be iterated over to manually calculate the sum of the differences... I guess with that addition I can accept your answer.

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand the last  step, mainly how did C become 2C?

Comment: Since $C$ does not depend on $p$ we can get it out of the sum: the sum contributes $n$ times a $C$, which gives $nC$, but there was a scalar of $2/n$ before the sum, so we have to multiply with this scalar to get $2C$.

Comment: Thank you! :) now I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivations are incorrect. The sum and $y_p$ terms do not vanish:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial C}C_0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial C} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n 
(y_p - C)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n 
\frac{\partial}{\partial C}  (y_p - C)^2 = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n (y_p - C)
= \frac{2}{n}\sum_{p = 1}^n y_p - 2C,
\end{align*}
where we use that the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives.

Comment: Hi! Thank you that is a welcome correction. would you mind if  I updated my question with it?